# How to clear HTML input textbox via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the same input textbox to collect multiple values.

After collecting the first input, I will clear the field by calling

```
document.getElementById("textbox").value= "";
```

On the surface, above snippet appears to clear the textbox. 
But when I blur the textbox by clicking elsewhere, the old value reappears.

MORE CODES >>>

My HTML >>

```
<input id="textbox" placeholder="Start">
```

Javascript >>

After getting the first input, I like to reset the input value >>>

```
document.getElementById("textbox").value= "";
document.getElementById("textbox").setAttribute("placeholder","End");
```

This is how I do my data collection >>>
The same textbox is first used to collect a Google "place", and then subsequently to collect some user entered comment. In addition to collecting the data, someFunction() also try to clear the textbox by calling .value= ""

```
google.maps.event.addListener(textbox, "place_changed", function() {
    someFunction();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code, please?

Comment: try using `.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: @limelights no ... just no

Comment: you may be storing the value during the onFocus() event. actually, that might be your only problem if .value doesn't reset. post more code, especially (but not only) the onBlur() and onFocus() calls

Comment: @limelights that's not helpful at all

Comment: Can both of you explain why?

Comment: So are you seeing the last user entered value on blur or you are seeing placeholder remaining as 'start' instead of 'end'

Comment: @raghavv: 1. User enters "AAA" when placeholder= "Start". 2. Textbox appears empty, with placeholder showing as ="End". 3. Clicking elsewhere on the browser will cause the textbox to show "AAA" as value

Comment: Can you please post all the event code on the input box?

Comment: @JanHančič I know why now. Sorry

Comment: @ngzhongcai How exactly are you handling the input collection? Are you using a submit button finalize the collection of the data from the input in it's first phrase of collection (http://jsfiddle.net/FTBRz/1/), or are you using some kind of keyboard event to check whether or not the data should be cleared?

Comment: @extramaster: I made edits to my post again. No "submit" buttons or forms. Data collection is triggered elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Here is something i found googling fast for an answer; i think you can play around indeed with onFocus() a bit:

```
<input type="text" value="Click here to clear text" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"/>
```

It may require a bit of usage of onBlur as well.

Also some other [pointer](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-change-default-value-on-focus/), to get you going with jQuery if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input's value is stored in separate variable to be used for some other actions. So you should maybe check your code and clear thar variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have practically implemented and used this solution whch is already suggested by my friend above:

```
document.getElementById("textbox").setAttribute("placeholder","End");
```

So, this works for me pretty well.(context:"placeholder" attribute used)

ICDT
..tc:)